Fps not showing aver canvas in Python tkinter
i wrote code for a window in python with a canvas as the background, but now my fps doesn‘t show. Would somebody explain me how to fix this?
I tried to first initialize the fps, but then i got a uncolored stripe. I have the code ready so would please somebody look over it and tell me what‘s causing my problem and how i van fix it?
import tkinter as tk
import time
import math

class FPSCounter:
  def __init__(self, window):
    self.frame_count = 0
    self.start_time = time.time()
    self.label = tk.Label(window, text="", font=("Calibri", 10), bg="lightblue", fg="white")
    self.label.pack(anchor="ne", padx=0, pady=0)
    self.visible = True
    self.update_fps()

def update_fps(self):
    if self.visible:
        self.frame_count += 1
        current_time = time.time()
        elapsed_time = current_time - self.start_time
        if elapsed_time >= 1:
            fps = self.frame_count / elapsed_time
            self.label.config(text=f"FPS: {int(fps)}")
            self.frame_count = 0
            self.start_time = current_time
        self.label.after(1, self.update_fps)

def toggle_visibility(self):
    self.visible = not self.visible
    if self.visible:
        self.label.pack(anchor="ne", padx=0, pady=0)
    else:
        self.label.pack_forget()

def main():
  window = tk.Tk()
  window.title("Fenster1")

  windowWidth = math.ceil((window.winfo_screenwidth()))
  windowHeight = math.ceil((window.winfo_screenheight()))

  window.geometry(f"{windowWidth}x{windowHeight}")

  canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=windowWidth, height=windowHeight)
  canvas.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

  start_color = (173, 216, 230)
  end_color = (30, 144, 255)

for i in range(windowHeight):
    r = int(start_color[0] - i * ((start_color[0] - end_color[0]) / windowHeight))
    g = int(start_color[1] - i * ((start_color[1] - end_color[1]) / windowHeight))
    b = int(start_color[2] - i * ((start_color[2] - end_color[2]) / windowHeight))
    color = f"#{r:02x}{g:02x}{b:02x}"
    canvas.create_line(0, i, windowWidth, i, fill=color)

fps_counter = FPSCounter(window)

def on_key_press(event):
    if event.keysym == "F3":
        fps_counter.toggle_visibility()

window.bind("<KeyPress>", on_key_press)

print("Fenster erstellt mit der Größe " + str(windowWidth) + "x" + str(windowHeight))

window.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()‘


This appears to be an indentation problem - in your code as shown, update_fps() and toggle_visibility() are top-level functions, rather than methods of the FPSCounter class.

In add of indentation problem, the label is at the bottom right. Try enlarging the windows. You should use place and place_forget instead of pack for label
